# How to print the variables matched by the symbol table in Boost spirit parser?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I am a beginner in using `boost spirit`

Say that I have the following code that parse a simple arithmetic expression with variables:

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/apply_visitor.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_function.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace client {
    namespace ast
    {
        struct nil {};
        struct signed_;
        struct program;

        typedef boost::variant<
            nil
            , double
            , boost::recursive_wrapper<signed_>
            , boost::recursive_wrapper<program>
        >
        operand;

        struct signed_
        {
            char sign;
            operand operand_;
        };

        struct operation
        {
            char operator_;
            operand operand_;
        };

        struct program
        {
            operand first;
            std::list<operation> rest;
        };
    }
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    client::ast::signed_,
    (char, sign)
    (client::ast::operand, operand_)
    )

    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    client::ast::operation,
    (char, operator_)
    (client::ast::operand, operand_)
    )

    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    client::ast::program,
    (client::ast::operand, first)
    (std::list<client::ast::operation>, rest)
    )

namespace client {
    namespace ast
    {
        struct eval
        {
            typedef double result_type;

            double operator()(nil) const { BOOST_ASSERT(0); return 0; }
            double operator()(double n) const { return n; }

            double operator()(operation const& x, double lhs) const
            {
                double rhs = boost::apply_visitor(*this, x.operand_);
                switch (x.operator_)
                {
                case '+': return lhs + rhs;
                case '-': return lhs - rhs;
                case '*': return lhs * rhs;
                case '/': return lhs / rhs;
                }
                BOOST_ASSERT(0);
                return 0;
            }

            double operator()(signed_ const& x) const
            {
                double rhs = boost::apply_visitor(*this, x.operand_);
                switch (x.sign)
                {
                case '-': return -rhs;
                case '+': return +rhs;
                }
                BOOST_ASSERT(0);
                return 0;
            }

            double operator()(program const& x) const
            {
                double state = boost::apply_visitor(*this, x.first);
                BOOST_FOREACH(operation const& oper, x.rest)
                {
                    state = (*this)(oper, state);
                }
                return state;
            }
        };
    }
}

namespace client
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
    using boost::phoenix::function;

    template <typename Iterator>
    struct calculator : qi::grammar<Iterator, ast::program(), ascii::space_type>
    {
        calculator() : calculator::base_type(expression)
        {
            qi::char_type char_;
            qi::double_type doubleParser_;

            symboleTable.add("var1", 2);
            symboleTable.add("var2", 15);
            symboleTable.add("var4", 5);
            symboleTable.add("var", 5);
            symboleTable.add("x", 5);

            expression =
                term
                >> *((char_('+') > term)
                | (char_('-') > term)
                )
                ;

            term =
                factor
                >> *((char_('*') > factor)
                | (char_('/') > factor)
                )
                ;

            factor =
                doubleParser_
                | symbolTable
                | '(' > expression > ')'
                | (char_('-') > factor)
                | (char_('+') > factor)
                ;
        }
        qi::symbols<char, double> symbolTable;
        qi::rule<Iterator, ast::program(), ascii::space_type> expression;
        qi::rule<Iterator, ast::program(), ascii::space_type> term;
        qi::rule<Iterator, ast::operand(), ascii::space_type> factor;
    };
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Main program
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int
main()
{
    std::cout << "/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n\n";
    std::cout << "Expression parser...\n\n";
    std::cout << "/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n\n";
    std::cout << "Type an expression...or [q or Q] to quit\n\n";

    typedef std::string::const_iterator iterator_type;
    typedef client::calculator<iterator_type> calculator;
    typedef client::ast::program ast_program;
    typedef client::ast::eval ast_eval;

    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, str))
    {
        if (str.empty() || str[0] == 'q' || str[0] == 'Q')
            break;

        calculator calc;        // Our grammar
        ast_program program;    // Our program (AST)
        ast_eval eval;          // Evaluates the program

        std::string::const_iterator iter = str.begin();
        std::string::const_iterator end = str.end();

        boost::spirit::ascii::space_type space;
        bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, calc, space, program);

        if (r && iter == end)
        {
            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
            std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
            std::cout << "\nResult: " << eval(program) << std::endl;
            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::string rest(iter, end);
            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
            std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Bye... :-) \n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I want to print the variables (not their values) when they are matched by the symbol table (declared in the grammar).

So for example when the input is

```
var* 2 - 3 +x*var2 - 2
```

the output should be:

```
var
x
var2
```

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AST used doesn't store the original variable referenced.

Hence **after** parsing the information is no longer available (the AST just contains value nodes instead of the original reference).

There are two ways about this:

- enrich the AST so you resolve variables at evaluation time only (keeping the variable reference names)

  > **UPDATE** I have added [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32501979/85371) that actually implements this, more elaborate, approach
- have the parser collect variable references "out-of-band" during parsing.

The latter requires vastly smaller effort (if you know the tricks of Spirit + Phoenix). So let's show that:

```
        factor =
            doubleParser_
            | variable
            | '(' > expression > ')'
            | (char_('-') > factor)
            | (char_('+') > factor)
            ;
```

Here I replaced the `symbolTable` by a new rule: `variable`:

```
    qi::rule<Iterator, double()> variable; // NOTE: also made it a lexeme (no skipper)
```

That rule still exposes just the value **but** as a side effect we will have it collect the reference into a set of variable names:

```
        variable %=  
               &qi::as_string[qi::raw[symbolTable]] 
                     [ px::insert(px::ref(collect_references), qi::_1) ] 
            >> symbolTable
            ;
```

As you can see, it is a quick-and-dirty approach leveraging a lot of Spirit tricks (`operator%=` auto-rule assignment, `qi::raw` and `qi::as_string` directives, `phoenix::insert` and the second parse by using the positive look-ahead assertion (`operator&`).

Now, we just need to pass in a `collect_references` container to the grammar, and we can print the references after successful parsing:

```
    std::set<std::string> collected_references;
    calculator calc(collected_references); // Our grammar

    if (r && iter == end)
    {
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
        std::cout << "References: ";
        std::copy(collected_references.begin(), collected_references.end(),
                std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));

        std::cout << "\nResult: " << eval(program) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
    }
```

It prints:

```
Type an expression...or [q or Q] to quit

var* 2 - 3 +x*var2 - 2
-------------------------
Parsing succeeded
References: var var2 x 
Result: 80
-------------------------
Bye... :-)
```

### DEMO CODE

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8978bfa369465f1)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/apply_visitor.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

namespace client {
    namespace ast
    {
        struct nil {};
        struct signed_;
        struct program;

        typedef boost::variant<
            nil
            , double
            , boost::recursive_wrapper<signed_>
            , boost::recursive_wrapper<program>
        >
        operand;

        struct signed_
        {
            char sign;
            operand operand_;
        };

        struct operation
        {
            char operator_;
            operand operand_;
        };

        struct program
        {
            operand first;
            std::list<operation> rest;
        };
    }
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    client::ast::signed_,
    (char, sign)
    (client::ast::operand, operand_)
    )

    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    client::ast::operation,
    (char, operator_)
    (client::ast::operand, operand_)
    )

    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    client::ast::program,
    (client::ast::operand, first)
    (std::list<client::ast::operation>, rest)
    )

namespace client {
    namespace ast
    {
        struct eval
        {
            typedef double result_type;

            double operator()(nil) const { BOOST_ASSERT(0); return 0; }
            double operator()(double n) const { return n; }

            double operator()(operation const& x, double lhs) const
            {
                double rhs = boost::apply_visitor(*this, x.operand_);
                switch (x.operator_)
                {
                case '+': return lhs + rhs;
                case '-': return lhs - rhs;
                case '*': return lhs * rhs;
                case '/': return lhs / rhs;
                }
                BOOST_ASSERT(0);
                return 0;
            }

            double operator()(signed_ const& x) const
            {
                double rhs = boost::apply_visitor(*this, x.operand_);
                switch (x.sign)
                {
                case '-': return -rhs;
                case '+': return +rhs;
                }
                BOOST_ASSERT(0);
                return 0;
            }

            double operator()(program const& x) const
            {
                double state = boost::apply_visitor(*this, x.first);
                BOOST_FOREACH(operation const& oper, x.rest)
                {
                    state = (*this)(oper, state);
                }
                return state;
            }
        };
    }
}

namespace client
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

    template <typename Iterator>
    struct calculator : qi::grammar<Iterator, ast::program(), ascii::space_type>
    {
        calculator(std::set<std::string>& collect_references) : calculator::base_type(expression)
        {
            qi::char_type char_;
            qi::double_type doubleParser_;

            symbolTable.add("var1", 2);
            symbolTable.add("var2", 15);
            symbolTable.add("var4", 5);
            symbolTable.add("var",  5);
            symbolTable.add("x",    5);

            namespace px = boost::phoenix;

            expression =
                term
                >> *((char_('+') > term)
                 |  (char_('-') > term)
                )
                ;

            term =
                factor
                >> *((char_('*') > factor)
                | (char_('/') > factor)
                )
                ;

            variable %=  
                   &qi::as_string[qi::raw[symbolTable]] 
                         [ px::insert(px::ref(collect_references), qi::_1) ] 
                >> symbolTable
                ;

            factor =
                doubleParser_
                | variable
                | ('(' > expression > ')')
                | (char_('-') > factor)
                | (char_('+') > factor)
                ;
        }
      private:
        qi::symbols<char, double> symbolTable;
        qi::rule<Iterator, double()> variable; // NOTE: also made it a lexeme (no skipper)
        qi::rule<Iterator, ast::program(), ascii::space_type> expression;
        qi::rule<Iterator, ast::program(), ascii::space_type> term;
        qi::rule<Iterator, ast::operand(), ascii::space_type> factor;
    };
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Main program
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int
main()
{
    std::cout << "/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n\n";
    std::cout << "Expression parser...\n\n";
    std::cout << "/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n\n";
    std::cout << "Type an expression...or [q or Q] to quit\n\n";

    typedef std::string::const_iterator iterator_type;
    typedef client::calculator<iterator_type> calculator;
    typedef client::ast::program ast_program;
    typedef client::ast::eval ast_eval;

    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, str))
    {
        if (str.empty() || str[0] == 'q' || str[0] == 'Q')
            break;

        std::set<std::string> collected_references;
        calculator calc(collected_references); // Our grammar
        ast_program program;                   // Our program (AST)
        ast_eval eval;                         // Evaluates the program

        std::string::const_iterator iter = str.begin();
        std::string::const_iterator end = str.end();

        boost::spirit::ascii::space_type space;
        bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, calc, space, program);

        if (r && iter == end)
        {
            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
            std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
            std::cout << "References: ";
            std::copy(collected_references.begin(), collected_references.end(),
                    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));

            std::cout << "\nResult: " << eval(program) << std::endl;
            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::string rest(iter, end);
            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
            std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Bye... :-) \n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Posted [another answer that does the "enhanced AST" approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32501979/85371). See the [recorded livestream](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/enriching-ast-for-variable-references-vs-qd/) in case you're interested in how I go about these answers. ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469))

Comment: sehe, you seem to be very knowledgeable about Boost. Wondering if you could check out a question I asked recently. I had not other way to get a hold of you...

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin Even I take breaks to eat and put the kids to bed :) 2 hours is not long...

Comment: sehe, I understand. Well, if you get a chance, here it is for quick reference:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483137/boost-semantic-actions-causing-parsing-issues

Comment: @Dylan_Larkin I obviously found it :). I'm doing something else first. Join me on https://www.livecoding.tv/sehe/ if you want to be sure to know as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 2):

The first, more involved [approach described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32501192/85371) modifies the AST to represent the variable references.

This has multiple advantages:

- the richer information allows you to do e.g. collection of variable references *after* the parse
- the delayed evaluation of variables allows reuse of the same AST with a different set of values for the variables! This is more like how actual interpreters work.

Let's start:

1. Modifying the AST:

   We want to be able to have a variable name in addition to the existing types of expressions:

   ```
   typedef boost::variant<
       nil
       , std::string // THIS LINE ADDED
       , double
       , boost::recursive_wrapper<signed_>
       , boost::recursive_wrapper<program>
   >
   operand;
   ```
2. Modifying the rule:

   Wwe want to keep the *name* of the variable instead of immediately replacing it by a fixed value:

   ```
       factor =
             qi::double_
           | qi::as_string[qi::raw[symbolTable]] // THIS LINE CHANGED
           | '(' > expression > ')'
           | (char_('-') > factor)
           | (char_('+') > factor)
           ;
   ```
3. Modifying the evalation visitor

   Now we need to "replace" the variables by their value *during* evaluation.

   Let's add a simple overload to the visitor:

   ```
   double operator()(std::string const& var) const { return symbols.at(var);    }
   ```

   We have given the visitor a reference to a map `symbols` for lookup:

   ```
   std::map<std::string, double>& symbols;
   eval(std::map<std::string, double>& symbols) : symbols(symbols) {}
   ```
4. Calling it from `main`:

   So we need to have a map of variables handy:

   ```
   std::map<std::string, double> symbols { {"var1", 2}, {"var2", 15}, {"var4", 5}, {"var", 5}, {"x", 5} };
   ```

   And pass a reference to the visitor:

   ```
   ast_eval eval(symbols) ; // Evaluates the program
   ```

---

At this point, the program operates exactly as the original program, but with an enriched AST:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0be26bc913905a26)</kbd>**

Printing

```
-------------------------
Parsing succeeded

Result: 80
-------------------------
```

---

### Enumerating variables referenced!

The point of the story becomes simple now: we just define another visitor like `eval` to extract references:

```
namespace client { namespace ast {
    struct extract_refs : boost::static_visitor<void>
    {
        std::set<std::string>& _references;

        extract_refs(std::set<std::string>& refs) : _references(refs) {}

        void operator()(std::string const& var) const { _references.insert(var);                 } 
        void operator()(operation const& x) const     { boost::apply_visitor(*this, x.operand_); } 
        void operator()(signed_ const& x) const       { boost::apply_visitor(*this, x.operand_); } 
        void operator()(program const& x) const       {
            boost::apply_visitor(*this, x.first);
            BOOST_FOREACH(operation const& oper, x.rest) (*this)(oper);
        }

        // ignore anything else
        template <typename Other> void operator()(Other const&) const {}
    };
} }
```

This can simply be *applied* to the AST:

```
std::set<std::string> references;
client::ast::extract_refs extract(references);

extract(program);

std::cout << "References: ";
std::copy(references.begin(), references.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
```

And the output once again becomes

```
-------------------------
Parsing succeeded
References: var var2 x 
Result: 80
-------------------------
```

Quod Erat Demonstrandum.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aefc328720f1d311)</kbd>**

Comment: Thank you very much, that's really great.
However, just a simple note, you have forgotten to include map in the mentioned code so when you try to compile the code in VS2013 you will get a compiler error.

Again, thank you very much this is greatly helpful.